# Config import on network-manager-openvpn

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to use a free service using the OpenVPN protocol using OpenVPN's GUI module in the network manager.

The config worked perfectly well as `.ovpn` on Windows. The behavior in Windows is such that I ran OpenVPN GUI and chose to connect to this particular VPN. It would then show the activity in the attempt to connect and opens a dialog box for username/password authentication.

I've successfully imported all the configurations by changing the file type to `.conf` and using the import feature in network manager. However, attempting to connect would simply display the network manager's attempting to connect animation, but ultimately end with a notification of connection timing out. No prompt asking for authentication would appear at all, nor can I find any feature to prefix the authentication details.

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote miami.proxpn.com 443 
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
cipher BF-CBC
keysize 512
comp-lzo
verb 4
mute 5
tun-mtu 1500
mssfix 1450
auth-user-pass
reneg-sec 0


# If you are connecting through an
# HTTP proxy to reach the actual OpenVPN
# server, put the proxy server/IP and
# port number here.  See the man page
# if your proxy server requires
# authentication.
;http-proxy-retry # retry on connection failures
;http-proxy [proxy server] [proxy port #]
```

Needless to say, but I've downloaded all the required packages for setting up OpenVPN connections.

By the way, as you can see above, `.key` and `.crt` files location are specified to be in the same directory as the config file. After importing the config file, if I were to remove them, would it cause any problem? Note, I haven't removed them, so the problem I'm facing is not due to the absence of these files.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try connecting to VPN from command line. This will make sure that the problem is with NetworkManager and not something else. You can connect from command line using:

```
openvpn --config /path/to/config.ovpn
```

You may need to run this command using sudo.

If you can successfully connect from command line then try adding yourself to `netdev` group and uncheck `Available to all users` in vpn settings window in NetworkManager and then try connecting using NM.

Comment: As expected, it connected perfectly on the attempt in Terminal. It did need `sudo` privileges.

Comment: So, did you try adding your self to 'netdev' group, unchecking 'Available to all users' in connection properties in Network Manager and then connecting through Network Manager ?

Comment: How do I do that on the command line? I'm on a minimal install, and the GUI for user management is not installed.

Comment: you can add user to 'netdev' group using following command "sudo usermod -aG netdev <user-name>"

Comment: ... It worked... But it didn't ask me to authenticate... WTF?

Comment: And please tag @Oxwivi when you comment, I won't get notified otherwise.

Comment: This helped me to make sure my connection is valid. I would be interested in how to proceed from here via command line. How would I connect to the openvpn server and then when the connection is up access the LAN on the server's side? If I run the command in shell I have to Ctrl-C the process to be able to put in another command. So how would I proceed while keeping the connection up?

Answer (score 3):

I think `tail -f /var/log/{syslog,messages}` followed by reconnecting the VPN could give some answers.

Comment: Reconnecting? It doesn't connect at all.

Comment: If it does not connect, it will spit out error messages.

Answer (score 1):

See the respective [bugreport on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/+bug/606365).