# Unable to add Cisco VPN connection

Tags: 12.04, vpn, cisco

I am setting up Cisco VPN on Ubuntu 12.04, when I run into strange behavior. I have downloaded and installed the following packages: `vpnc network-manager-vpnc` and dependencies.

When adding the connection with network manager, I am not able to save the connection - I only get this error

[image: VPN error]

I have tried different settings, tried importing cisco `.pcf` without any luck so far.

#### Errors

While searching for solutions, I have stumbled upon a way to restart the network manager applet:

`killall nm-applet; nm-applet &`

This did not solve my problems, but I noticed that a log is written to the terminal after running the command, and I think it may tell something (no idea what, though!)

After clicking save, these lines are written in the terminal:

```
(nm-applet:4079): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_async_initable_real_init_finish: assertion `g_simple_async_result_is_valid (res, G_OBJECT (initable), g_async_initable_real_init_async)' failed

** (nm-applet:4079): CRITICAL **: dbus_g_error_has_name: assertion `error != NULL' failed

(nm-applet:4079): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_error_free: assertion `error != NULL' failed

(nm-connection-editor:4157): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_async_initable_real_init_finish: assertion `g_simple_async_result_is_valid (res, G_OBJECT (initable), g_async_initable_real_init_async)' failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Useful suggestions here [Config import on network-manager-openvpn](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27168/config-import-on-network-manager-openvpn?rq=1)
which helped me to establish that my problem (same symptoms as above) are down to the network manager and not openvpn itself.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem & just fixed it.
I've installed gnome3 using ricotz's ppa. Before I had some problems with gnome-shell-extensions so I've downgraded it to gnome3-team ppa packages (maybe it takes a part).
To fix nm problem I've downgraded libglib2.0-0 from ricotz's version to precise-updates.
I've made this by synaptic (package->force version), but I think cli version is

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0/precise-updates
```